# Set default tab to Angular.js tabs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tabs, ng-class

I have an `Angular.js` component which has a list of tabs. When a tab is clicked I assign an `ng-class`to it (active), so it gets highlighted. This is working fine, but I also want the first tab to be the default active one when a user first load the page, but at the moment nothing is highlighted when I load the page.

Here's my component:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('menuBar').component('menuBar', {
    templateUrl: 'menu-bar/menu-bar.template.html',
    controller: function menuBarController() {
        this.menus = [
            {
                name: 'Tab1'
            }, {
                name: 'Tab2'
            }, {
                name: 'Tab3'
            }, {
                name: 'Tab4'
            }, {
                name: 'Tab5'
            }
        ];

        this.tab = this.menus[0].name;

        this.setTab = function (tabId) {
            this.tab = tabId;
        }

        this.isSet = function (tabId) {
            return this.tab === tabId;
        }
    }
});
```

Here my html template:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="container">   
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li ng-repeat="menu in $ctrl.menus" ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(menu.name)}">
                <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(menu.name)">{{menu.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Maybe something wrong at this line here where I'm trying to set my default tab?

```
this.tab = this.menus[0].name;
```

### Update: Plunker added

[Live preview here](https://plnkr.co/edit/FC5YhnbhkZWRE2wXlxSn?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-collapse">
<div class="container">   
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li ng-repeat="menu in $ctrl.menus" ng-class="     active:menu.name==$ctrl.tab}">
            <a href ng-click="$ctrl.setTab(menu.name)">{{menu.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>  
</div>
```

Comment: Please share plunker for replication the issue.

Comment: I have fixed this issue you an see here. https://plnkr.co/edit/JYpzKoTfKgX8SND1Hwcp?p=preview

Comment: Your code is working, but mine not. I don't understand what changes you've made. Would you mind to modify my plunker?

Comment: <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-collapse">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- changes are commented line -->
    <!-- ng-class="{active:menu.name==$ctrl.tab}" -->
    <!--<a href ng-click="$ctrl.setTab(menu.name)">-->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li ng-repeat="menu in $ctrl.menus" ng-class="{active:menu.name==$ctrl.tab}">
        <a href ng-click="$ctrl.setTab(menu.name)">{{menu.name}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>

Comment: Yessss, Thanks a lot! If you update your answer I can accept it

Comment: I have updated the code . try running that.https://plnkr.co/edit/JdmV9j?p=preview

Comment: Oh actually the first tab stays always active, even when I select other ones

Comment: do this   <a href ng-click="$ctrl.setTab(menu.name)">{{menu.name}}</a>

Comment: Yep brilliant, it works. Pease edit your answer with these changes, so I can give u points

Answer (score 0):

You can use `orderBy`:

> Function: A getter function. This function will be called with each item as argument and the return value will be used for sorting.

I'm not sure about the syntax since I haven't used components yet but something among the lines:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="container">   
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li ng-repeat="menu in $ctrl.menus | orderBy: $ctrl.isSet(tab.id)" ng-class="{active:tab.isSet(menu.name)}">
                <a href ng-click="tab.setTab(menu.name)">{{menu.name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will only sort my tabs. It's not assigning the 'active' class to the first